# How to draw a scale or a graduated marker on QGIS?

Tags: qgis

[image]I need to place points at regular intervals on a map. How can I proceed?
In order to have regular spacing and have my rectangles all aligned, I need a tool to place my points with regular spacing. So I need a graduated marker

Comment: Why does the question title talk about drawing a scale or graduated marker and then the question text says something else? What are you trying to do? Can you add a picture of what you want to get and what data you have?

Comment: In order to have regular spacing and have my rectangles all aligned, I need a tool to place my points with regular spacing. So I need a graduated marker.

Comment: Please provide an example of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I would like to reposition my points so that my purple rectangles are aligned and the green and purple rectangles are evenly spaced.

Comment: So you already have these data but you want them aligned and regularly spaced? Or are you trying to draw them in QGIS and have them all aligned and spaced as you do it?

Comment: This has the feel of an XY Problem, where you are asking about how to implement your solution instead of asking about solving the problem itself. It would help if you step back further and explain the actual task.

Comment: I already have my rectangles but I can recreate them if needed. I was waiting for an answer before continuing by modifying the attribute tables. 
In reply to Vince; The problem is that my stitches are not aligned and evenly spaced

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it would be to trace a line perpendicular to your polygons then use the "Points along geometry" tool to place regularly spaced points on it. This way your points will be aligned and have an equal interval between them.

To create the line you may want to use the Advanced Digitizing panel to draw a line with specific length and azimuth.

Below see a 10 000m line over Paris with an angle of 126° with interpolated point at 500m interval

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much !!!